# how to make the affect only applies on the changed component only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

whenever i try. to change an input it's show the 2 component changes of input at the same time how i show only the changed one

input.tsx

```
export const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ type, placeholder, classNameProp, value, onChange, forwardRef, isReadOnly = false, isRequired = true, errorText }) => {
  console.log(forwardRef?.current);

  return (
    <>
      <input type={type} placeholder={placeholder} className={`p-2 mb-4 rounded-sm border-b-2 border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:border-orange-500 ${classNameProp}`} value={value} onChange={onChange} disabled={isReadOnly} required={isRequired} ref={forwardRef} />
    </>
  );
};
```

formSurvey.tsx

```
export const SurveyForm: React.FC<SurveyFormProps> = () => {
  const titleRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const subjectRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const [surveyTitle, setSurveyTitle] = React.useState("");
  const [surveySubject, setSurveySubject] = React.useState("");
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(surveyTitle);
    let state: any = {
      title: surveyTitle,
      subject: surveySubject,
    };
  };

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <form className="max-w-3xl mx-auto bg-white rounded-xl p-5 mb-6" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Input type="text" placeholder="Survey Title" classNameProp={`w-full ${titleRef.current?.value.length === 0 ? "border-red-500" : ""}`} value={surveyTitle} onChange={React.useCallback(setter(setSurveyTitle), [])} forwardRef={titleRef} errorText="Please fill the title field" />

        <Input type="text" placeholder="Subject Line" classNameProp={`w-full ${subjectRef.current?.value.length === 0 ? "border-red-500" : ""}`} value={surveySubject} onChange={React.useCallback(setter(setSurveySubject), [])} forwardRef={subjectRef} errorText="Please fill the subject field" />

        <div className="form-footer flex justify-center space-x-10">
          <button className="bg-orange-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-3xl font-semibold" type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

setter.ts

```
type Set<T> = React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>;
type ChangeEvent<E> = React.ChangeEvent<E>;
type Input = HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement;
export function setter<T extends number | string | Date, E extends Input = HTMLInputElement>(setX: Set<T>) {
  return (e: ChangeEvent<E>) => {
    setX(e.target.value as T);
  };
}
```

try to find the best way to implement reusable component  in react js

you can see the code here also [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-heisenberg-5hkd37?file=/src/SurveyForm.tsx)

Comment: What you mean by "it's show the 2 component changes of input at the same time"?

Comment: @OktayYuzcan i mean when i change one input and see the changes in console i see the changes of the other input component for example i need to use something like (this) keyword in js to know which one i change it   ,can you check the code here https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-heisenberg-5hkd37?file=/src/SurveyForm.tsx

Comment: I still don't get what you mean by "changes in console". I do not see any changes in the second input while changing the value in the first one. Do you mean you re-render all inputs when you change value in one of them?

Comment: for example when i change the surveyTitle and track the changes of it at the same time see the tack change on surveySubject which i don't' want when i change the title only

Comment: So you mean you see the re-render of the second input aswell? Tracking the changes is different than the tracking the re-renders. The second input does not change, but it re-render. Is this what you mean?

Comment: yes similar to that

Answer (score 0):

Since you use state, whenever you call setState, each children re-renders. If the components are not so big, most of the time re-renders don't matter and everything is fast enough (optimized)

But if you want to optimize this, there are techniques you can use to avoid unnecessary renders.

The quickest solution for you would be to use React.memo to wrap your inputs.

```
const Input = React.memo(...your component body)
```

Or you can use uncontrolled inputs.

Or some library that does this for you, like react-hook-form